# URL in new line Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, line-breaking, urls, ieeetran

I'm being asked to put the url field in a new line after the reference information. Is there a way to do this using IEEEtran?

Edit:
Noting the initial suggestions, you can find the idea of the task using the following images:

What I would like is the url to be in a new line like this image:

[image: Objective]

And I have cases like this one:

[image: Challenge]

Using the field of note instead of url like this:

note = {\ \href{http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6315362&isnumber=6314593}{http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=\&arnumber=6315362\&isnumber=6314593}}

I have:
[image: Attempt]

It looks like what I want but I would still like find a different approach, mainly to replace the comma after the year for a period.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please post a minimum working example (MWE) of what you've done so far. This would help a lot in terms of coming up with possible solutions.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://tex.se/)! Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: Wish this question had been posed for BibTeX plain instead of IEEEtran.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `IEEEtran` bibtex style has an interesting mechanism for customizing the bibliography.  It is documented in `IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf`, see [IEEEtran bibtex on ctan](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/).

You create a special entry in the bibliography file, of type `@IEEEtranBSTCTL`, where you can adjust various parameters for the bibliography style.  Amongst these, the "text" printed before `url` fields is controlled by the field `CTLname_url_prefix`.  By default it is `"[Online]. Available:"`.

So one possibility is to change that text to start with the command `\par`, starting a new paragraph.  An alternative would be `\linebreak{}`, which would attempt to stretch the previous line to the right margin.  (The extra braces `{}` would be needed because af the following square bracket at `[Online]` in this case, which should not be interpreted as an optional argument.)

Now you need to cite this styling entry before your other citations in the main document via the special command `\bstctlcite`.

Here is an example:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}

Text with citation~\cite{test}.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} 
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,ref}
\end{document}
```

with `ref.bib` containing

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
  CTLname_url_prefix = "\par [Online]. Available:",
}

@InProceedings{test,
  author =   {Chamseddine, A. and Tong Li and Youmin Zhang and
                  Rabbath, C.-A. and Theilliol, D.},
  booktitle =    {American Control Conference (ACC), 2012},
  title =    {Flatness-based trajectory planning for a quadrotor
                  Unmanned Aerial Vehicle test-bed considering
                  actuator and system constraints},
  year =     {June},
  pages =    {920-925},
  issn =     {0743-1619},
  url = {http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6315362&isnumber=6314593}
}
```