# Limiting Citations in Bibliography with IEEE style

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, zotero

I'm using the IEEE conference style and am exporting my bibTeX from Zotero. Zotero however just adds all information into the bibTeX and then my TeX-environment just compiles all that information into the PDF, leading to a really long bibliography section with all kinds of useless information. I'm using the `\bibliography{IEEEabrv,MyBib}`.

What is the best way to limit what information appears in the bibliography? Sure, I could just manually remove the information from bibTeX, but there must be a more elegant solution. Does the IEEE tex-style somewhere define what information will be added?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  If you just use `\cite` commands for the entries you use, and do not have a `\nocite{*}` in the document, then by default the bibliography will only contain the entries you reference.

Comment: To clarify, it not the amount of entires in the bibliography that are bothering me, but the addional information such as DOI, the extra field from Zotero, other URLs, and so on.

Comment: There are various formatting directives you can adjust, cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102913/15925.  However, the information you are talking about is in fields that should be ignored by the style.  Please post a MWE.

Answer (score 1):

You can try clearing the fields you don't want:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{
 \clearlist{address}
 \clearfield{eprint}
 \clearfield{doi}
 \clearfield{issn}
 \clearlist{location}
 \clearfield{month}
 \clearfield{series}
 \clearname{editor}
}
```

Look at the `biblatex` documentation to find out whether the field is indeed a field, a list, or a name in order to use the right function to clear it.

Comment: Despite the label, I don't think the OP is actually using `biblatex`.  Although, I admit that it is not clear based on the question as it is currently written.  I think people are often confused as to what the tag means (often perhaps no more than 'BIBliography' + 'LATEX'?).